# Dropdown menu not pushing content down despite 'position: relative'

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, position

I am having a problem with a simple jQuery dropdown. It's not pushing down the content that's below it. I've given them all `position: relative`, but still no joy. It keeps floating on top of it. How can I correct this?

**EDIT:** Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8arUF/) as suggested!

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav-mobile">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>audio-visual-company/audio-visual-company.php">Why Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>audio-visual-hire/audio-visual-hire.php">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>sound-hire/sound-hire.php">Our Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>video-production-dublin/video-production-dublin.php">Video Production</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>audio-visual-dublin/audio-visual-dublin-contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<header id="header">
    <a href="../index.php"><img src="gfx/logo.png" alt="Conference Services" id="logo" /></a>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
#nav-mobile {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 12px;
    height: 33px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
#nav-mobile, #nav-mobile ul, #nav-mobile li {
    position: relative; 
}
#nav-mobile ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #151515;
}
#nav-mobile ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
    padding: 13px 0 13px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav-mobile ul a:hover {
    background: none;   
}
#nav-mobile ul li:hover {
    background: #272727;    
}
header {
    height: 150px;  
}
```

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle to accompany this code? It would help us see what the issue is. Thanks!

Comment: no probs here you go ! http://jsfiddle.net/8arUF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `height` to `auto`:

```
#nav-mobile {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 12px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 33px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<body>
<div id="nav-mobile">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>audio-visual-company/audio-visual-company.php">Why Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>audio-visual-hire/audio-visual-hire.php">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>sound-hire/sound-hire.php">Our Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>video-production-dublin/video-production-dublin.php">Video Production</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="<?php echo $path; ?>audio-visual-dublin/audio-visual-dublin-contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <header id="header">
    <a href="../index.php"><img src="gfx/logo.png" alt="Conference Services" id="logo" /></a>
</header>
    </div>
</body>
```

Working example : [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rakeshurgreat/ALjnd/)

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, that's working indeed. It's not an ideal solution for me however, since I wanna hide div#nav-mobile in default and show it only for mobile devices, and I obviously need the header all the time.  If you have any more ideas please share.

Answer (score 1):

just need to add this to the CSS ID and it should work as expected.

```
#nav-mobile{
  min-height:33px;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, that was it indeed! Mati, however, was first so I'd have to give the best answer to him. Thanks for your feedback anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Its not pushing down because both are separate entities i am talking about navigation and content. Put your markup together and see the result like this

```
<div id="nav-mobile">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Why Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Video Production</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
<header id="header">
    LOGO
</header>

</div>
```

please check the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8arUF/1/).